# Problems With Locator Position Resetting

Tags: graphics, locator

I am currently attempting to write code that allows users to add shapes to a window and arrange them to create an image. To do this, I make each shape into a locator. This method seems to work well. However, whenever I add a new shape in to the window using the buttons, all of the shapes move back to the initial point they were set to. Clearly, this isn't ideal for creating a good user experience. I have tried making the locator initial point dynamic; however, all of the shapes are still reset to their initial point and also stick together. Does anyone have suggestions as to how I could alter this code so that the shapes retain the position they were moved to even when a new shape is added? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
designWindowTest[] := CreateWindow[DialogNotebook[{
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, listOfShapes = {}, ptList = {}},
 Row[{
   Column[{
     Button["Red Disk", AppendTo[ptList, pt]; 
      AppendTo[listOfShapes, 
       Locator[ptList[[Length[ptList]]], 
        Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Small]]]],

     Button["Blue Disk", AppendTo[ptList, pt]; 
      AppendTo[listOfShapes, 
       Locator[ptList[[Length[ptList]]], 
        Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Small]]]],

     Button["Green Disk", AppendTo[ptList, pt]; 
      AppendTo[listOfShapes, 
       Locator[ptList[[Length[ptList]]], 
        Graphics[{Green, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Small]]]],

     Button["Exit", DialogReturn[]],

     Graphics[{Dynamic@Text[ptList]}]
     }],(*end of column*)
   Dynamic@
    Graphics[{listOfShapes}, PlotRange -> 1, 
     ImageSize -> {1100, 1000}]
   }](*end of row*)

 ]}], WindowSize -> Full, Background -> White]
```

Comment: Did I answer your question?

Comment: Yes- thank you very much!

Comment: I suggest that you upvote the answers you like and [accept](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the one that you like the most or the one that works for you. Please, take the quick [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the value `Length[ptList]` in a different context each time you create a new shape, otherwise it always points to the last element in the list. I have done this with `With`.

By using `Dynamic@ptList[[np]]` the values in `ptList` are updated if the locator is moved. This prevents the reset of the positions when a new shape is added.

```
designWindowTest[] := 
 CreateWindow[
  DialogNotebook[{DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}, listOfShapes = {}, 
      ptList = {}}, 
     Row[{Column[{Button["Red Disk", AppendTo[ptList, pt];

          AppendTo[listOfShapes, 
           Locator[With[{np = Length[ptList]}, Dynamic[ptList[[np]]]],
             Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Small]]]], 
         Button["Blue Disk", AppendTo[ptList, pt];

          AppendTo[listOfShapes, 
           Locator[With[{np = Length[ptList]}, Dynamic[ptList[[np]]]],
             Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Small]]]], 
         Button["Blue Disk", AppendTo[ptList, pt];

          AppendTo[listOfShapes, 
           Locator[With[{np = Length[ptList]}, Dynamic[ptList[[np]]]],
             Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> Small]]]], 
         Button["Exit", DialogReturn[]], 
         Graphics[{Dynamic@Text[ptList]}]}],(*end of column*)
       Dynamic@Graphics[{listOfShapes}, PlotRange -> 1, 
         ImageSize -> {400, 400}]}](*end of row*)]}], 
  WindowSize -> 600, Background -> White]
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't exactly say what is the problem with your example, but I can show you my approach to solve the problem. It may not be the most robust and elegant code, although I think it can be easily extended with additional functionality.

Helper functions, to increase the readability of the main function/expression.

```
ClearAll[shape];
Attributes[shape] = {HoldFirst};
shape[pt_, color_] := Locator[Dynamic[pt], Graphics[{color, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 20]]

ClearAll[removeShape];
Attributes[removeShape] = {HoldAll};
removeShape[crds_, colors_] := Button["remove shape",
  If[Length[crds] > 1,
   crds = Most[crds]; colors = Most[colors];
   ]
  ]

ClearAll[addShape];
Attributes[addShape] = {HoldAll};
addShape[name_, col_, crds_, colors_] := Button[
  name <> " disk",
  AppendTo[crds, {0, 0}]; AppendTo[colors, col];
  ]
```

The main `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{
  crds = {{0, 0}},
  colors = {Red}
  },
 Column[{
   Row[{
     addShape["red", Red, crds, colors],
     addShape["blue", Blue, crds, colors],
     addShape["random", RandomColor[], crds, colors],
     removeShape[crds, colors]
     },
    Spacer[3]
    ]
   ,
   Graphics[
    Dynamic[
     Table[
      With[{i = i},
       shape[crds[[i]], colors[[i]]]
       ],
      {i, 1, Length[crds]}
      ]
     ],
    ImageSize -> 300
    ]
   }, Frame -> All],
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

[image: canvas]